# Cannot download the newest version of dbt

Tags: dbt

I wanted to install dbt on my wsl, but it keeps downloading only the old version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB09c.png).

Tried to upgrade using

```
pip install --upgrade dbt-<adapter>
```

but it doesnt work. While upgrating I see this log:

```
Using cached dbt_bigquery_0.21.1-py3-none-any.whl (30 kb)
```

Not sure how to solve it. I dont have any projects yet.

Comment: I'd suggest uninstalling it (`pip uninstall dbt-<adapter>`) and install the specific version you want (`pip install dbt-<adapter>==1.5.0`)

Comment: welcome to SO. Please don't use images of code/errors. For more info: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

`pip` keeps a cache of downloaded objects, which can mess with version resolution sometimes. You can try the `--no-cache-dir` option to tell it to ignore its cache:

```
pip install --upgrade dbt-bigquery --no-cache-dir
```

Or better yet, use a version specifier:

```
pip install --upgrade dbt-bigquery==1.5.0 --no-cache-dir
```